# Logging into a website via C#, navigating to another web page, and then output the source code as a string

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am relatively new to working with web pages in C#. What I am trying to do is log into a particular website ( https://www15.swalife.com/PortalWeb/portal/cwaLogon.jsp ) and allowing the page to be redirected to the default page, and then navigating from there to (https://www15.swalife.com/csswa/ea/plt/accessELITT.do) and downloading the source code and output it to a string.

I have figured out how to download the source code via HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebResponse but am having trouble on coding the logging in function. I assume I will have to do something with  POST? I have looked at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/152297-c%23-log-in-to-website-programmatically/ also.

### Thanks in advance!!

### EDIT:

The code supplied by jimmyjambles works flawlessly, except it doesn't quite get me the source code of the page I wanted. The code suggests that the log-in process failed, but I believe with a little bit of tweaking I could get it to work...also to everyone having issues with:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

Try changing your "public string" and "public bool" functions to "public static string" and "public static bool" respectively :)

### EDIT 2:

Response HTML:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">\n<META name=\"GENERATOR\" content=\"IBM WebSphere Studio\">\n<TITLE>endSession.jsp</TITLE>\n<LINK rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"eipPortletStyles/swalife.css\" type=\"text/css\">\n\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"JavaScript\" \n\t\tsrc=\"eipCommonJavaScript/eipGeneralFunctions.js\"/> </script>\n\t\t\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n\n\tfunction refreshParent()\n\t{\n\t    if(window.parent)\n\t    {\n\t    if(window.parent.name == 'appMainFrame')\n\t       window.parent.location = \"/csswa/ea/plt/logout.do\";\n\t    //  alert('Your session has expired.  Please login again. ');\n\t    }\n\t}\n\n</script>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY onload=\"refreshParent();\">\n \n\t \t<div class=\"eipErrors\">\n  \t\t\t<div class=\"legendLabel\">Message</div>\n  \t\t\t\n  \t\t\t    <div class=\"errorsHeader formTitle\">You Have Exited Out of Crew Web Access.<br>  \t\t\t \n  \t\t\t    </div>\n  \t\t\t \n  \t\t\t<div class=\"errorsHeader formTitle\"> Please Close this Window and <font  size=\"+1\">Log Out of SWALife</font> to Complete the Log Out Process.  </div>\n  \t\t<div class=\"errorsText\">\n  \t\t  &nbsp;\n  \t\t\t\t\n  \t\t</div>\n  \t\t\n  \t\t\t\n  \t\t\n  \t\t<div class=\"errorsFooter\">You will need to log back in before continuing.</div>  \t\n  \t\t\n \t</div>\n  \n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n"
```

Comment: Do you have a legit reason for creating something to automatically log into that website?

Comment: What have tried? What was the problem? Did you you get an error?

Comment: Yes, I am designing a program to automatically perform flight swaps for southwest pilots...primarily just for myself

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich  It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use HttpWebRequest to access a secondary URL after login you will need to keep in mind a few things.

Firstly as Casperah has mentioned you will need to inspect the login form and identify the "name" attribute of the controls used to receive the login data.

Once you have done this you will need to format a post string accordingly and provide it to the WebRequest.

The last consideration is that once you have logged in, you will need to store and maintain the cookie assigned to you from the server that keeps you logged in.

I have taken a WebRequest snippet from [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) and modified it to perform a second page request after the login.

```
        string loginurl = "http://www.gmail.com";
        string secondurl = "http://mail.google.com/prefs";

        string username = "bob@gmail.com";
        string password = "12345";
        GetSecondaryLoginPage(loginurl, secondurl, username, password);



    public string GetSecondaryLoginPage(string loginurl, string secondurl, string username, string password, string cookieName = null)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginurl);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";

        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        if (cookieName != null)
            container.Add(new Cookie(cookieName, username, "/", new Uri(loginurl).Host));

        request.CookieContainer = container;

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  Modify this line accordingly
        string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamWriter outfile =
        new StreamWriter("output.html"))
        {
            outfile.Write(responseFromServer.ToString());
        }

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(secondurl);
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        response = request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }


    public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The only added lines are for the postData and cookies.

You will need to modify the line

```
string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", username, password);
```

based on your controls on the form, since you posted the site your trying to work with I can guess that you are probably looking for

```
string postData = String.Format("uid={0}&portalBase=cwa&password={1}", username, password);
```

Comment: The only issue I am having is that VS is saying "AcceptAllCertifications does not exist in the current context"...

Comment: apologies, forgot to include it, I added the function at the bottom of the code snippet, you can just disable the line as well but it ensures that the login will work even if the site has an untrusted certificate, feel free to vote up if it works

Comment: I did some research and managed to find that particular line myself, but thanks for the update to know that I'm headed in the right direction...I also determined in order for the code to not receive errors that that bool must be static since the above on is (for reference in different forms) I will be testing it now! :D

Comment: Also voting up requires 15 reputation :P and this is my first post on this website haha

Comment: I see, Im just getting started here as well.  You are right, static functions can only call other static functions.  If the code is still not working I suggest looking at the "string postData = ..." line.  Put a breakpoint in the function and see what responseFromServer is on the first response "string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();", if the source you receive is still the login page, then you know you need to tweak your post variables, check if that's it and let me know, if that's the case Ill help you correct it

Comment: The source that I am getting is for a "Your HTTP Session expired" page sent out by the server saying that the user isn't logged in. I have tried various versions of the string PostData but get either the same page, or an error at the GetRequestStream()

Comment: did you try the breakpoint?  Comment out everything in the function after the line "string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();" and see what response you get.

Comment: also, did you switch the line I mentioned at the bottom, "string postData = String.Format("uid={0}&portalBase=cwa&password={1}", username, password);"

Comment: The returned response is null? 0_o

Comment: And yes I did change that...I am a bit confused here haha

Comment: I mean put the breakpoint on the next line, so that it can execute before breaking.

Comment: I took a look at the jsp page in question and added a line to the code to create the cookie before the first request, it seems that this is necessary when working with jsp

Comment: I modified the function to be more generic, remember to switch the line I mentioned before again and in your case you should pass cookieName = "userNameCookie"

Comment: Hello...I am just now revisiting this section of my program and unfortunately I am still unable to obtain the source code I am looking for :/ I will continue to tweak as necessary. I would also like to thank you for the time you have spent helping me with my project.

Comment: My pleasure, you can't be too far from getting it should just require a bit of playing around.

Answer (score 0):

Using a WebBrowser in a form is fairly easy.  Start by navigating to the cwaLogon.jsp page and locate the input-controls and Invoke "click" on the submit button.
Either that or make the appropriate GET/POSTs using HTTPWebRequest and Response.
Using Fiddler2 to check what to post is a great start.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will certainly check this out and post my code for others to view if this works...Although I still don't understand how to fill out a form and invoke a "click" on a submit button, I'm sorry but I'm really new to this...