# Connecting to a second url after logging in

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create some software that can collect the odds from several different bookies and display them in a way that shows which bets are best to place based on some calculations I make with the odds and liquidity in the markets etc. There is a website which I subscribe to that displays odds from different bookies called oddsmonkey, so I want to connect to this website rather than the bookies individually.

I seem to be getting a problem when I'm trying to log into this page:
https://www.oddsmonkey.com/OddsMonkeyLogin/tabid/76/Default.aspx?returnurl=%2f
 When I try to go to a second page, I get redirected back to this login page, despite me trying to store the login details in a cookie. Here is my current code:

```
static void getResponse(string loginUrl, string secondUrl, string username, string password, string cookieName = null)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";

        CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        if (cookieName != null)
        {
            container.Add(new Cookie(cookieName, username, "/", new Uri(loginUrl).Host));
        }

        //Need to somehow find the name of the inputs for username and password, as I think I 
        //currently have them incorrect.

        string postData = String.Format("Username={0}&Password={1}", username, password);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\tempFile1.xml"))
        {
            outfile.Write(responseFromServer.ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(secondUrl);
        request.CookieContainer = container;

        response = request.GetResponse();

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\jacko\\Documents\\tempFile.xml"))
        {
            outfile.Write(responseFromServer.ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    public static bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, 
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, 
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I got most of this code from this post:
[Logging into a website via C#, navigating to another web page, and then output the source code as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954004/logging-into-a-website-via-c-navigating-to-another-web-page-and-then-output-t)

I really appreciate any help, hopefully my error isn't something too stupid.